# View Controller call method on Sub View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller that has a `UIButton` in it. I have a `UIView` in that View Controller that accepts signatures. There is a `.h` and `.m` file associated with the `UIView`. The `UIView's` `.m` file has an erase method. I want the `UIButton` in my View Controller to be able to call that erase method, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's the code I was trying:

```
-(IBAction)clearButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    SignatureView *SC = [[SignatureView alloc] init];
    [SC erase];
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
}
```

The `NSLog` works, so I know that the action is being called. What gives?

EDIT:

It's answer worked; sort of.

`NSLog(@"Erased");` is working, so I know the button is working, but it doesn't erase. Here's the erase code:

```
- (void)erase {
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"Erased");
}
```

Comment: You're creating a brand new `SignatureView` instance and then calling `erase` on it, then ignoring it forever. You need to call `erase` on the instance your view controller already has.

Comment: @CarlVeazey - Got it. Where is the UIView initialized?

Comment: Either somewhere in your code, or in a nib / storyboard. Search for strings like `SignatureView alloc` or `SignatureView new`, and also look at the view hierarchy in the nib, examining the class of each view with the Inspector.

Comment: Check this code https://github.com/MasudShuvo/TestUIViewMethodCall, Here an delegate also has been set to get the response that the method has been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is to create a new instance of `SignatureView` and call this instance to erase. 
If you are using nib, then `outlet` the view to you `ViewController` named such as `aSignatureView` and in the `clearButtonPressed` call `[aSignatureView erase];`
If you add the `SignatureView` through code, then you should keep the view as one of instance members such as `aSignatureView`, and then call `[aSignatureView erase];`